# Intellij - Errors JAVA (imports, etc...) doesn't detect

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, ide

I'm starting use the `IntelliJ-IDEA`, but my `java` files doesn't detect errors like imports for example. I don't create one project `java`, because i'm using different languages in same project, but I want that in the `java` files, he detect the errors. How can I make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellij can work very well standard project layouts. If yours is not standard - tell Intellij how it is structured: from open workspace, select File -> Project Structure (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S), and go through all the tabs to setup specifics:

The most important tabs are probably:

1. Project tab, where you specify jdk to use with the project (JAVA_HOME if you will)
2. Modules -> Sources where you tell intellij which directories should be treated as java packages
3. Modules -> Paths to setup where you want to put compiled classes
4. Modules -> Libraries - to specify any additional jars to be used.

Assume you have two java files in your project:

```
package com.myproject // this one have package

public class SomeClass{
    //whatever
}
```

and

```
public class Main {
    // whatever - no package
}
```

so you should have them inside some directory:

```
directory
  |- com
  |  |- mypackage
  |     |- SomeClass.java
  |- Main.java
```

In such structure - the `directory` is sources root. Mark it as such

Comment: But I put this and java don't say errors for example imports and that things... 

This is not correct? http://s17.postimg.org/4elqml1kv/Captura_de_ecr_de_2015_11_18_21_32_41.png

Comment: "Modules -> Sources where you tell intellij which directories should be treated as java packages"

I have to put with source the folders that I want that intelliJ recognise with java?

Comment: I'd rather see the module -> source tab screen next compared to the directory layout where you store your code.

Comment: Yes it works!! the source for the folders of java !! thanks!! :D

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem where Intellij doesn't detect even a String, When your Intellij behaves abnormally, finds errors where there are none, outdated debugging, etc. It may be necessary to invalidate its cache (which is easily corruptible). You go to:

[image: Intellij Invalidate Caches...]

And select Clear file system cache option

[image: Intellij clear file system cache]

After clicking on Invalidate and Restart the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you!  I switched JDKs and IntelliJ refused to see a lot of my classes, even after a fresh git clone.  Invalidating caches worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

In my case only java.* imports were not detected.

- I am using gradle - java 11 (Spring boot)

These are the steps I did

- File -> Project Structure
- Changed the Project SDK from adopt-open-jdk11 to Amazon-coretto-11
- Click Apply

Answer (score 0):

- Go to File -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDKs.
- Remove the SDK you're using by clicking on "-" sign.
- Add the SDK you want to use by clicking on "+" sign. You can also add the same SDK that you removed in previous step.
- Apply.