# IntelliJ not adding Java as a depend

Tags: java, intellij-idea, buildpath

I made a new project in IntelliJ and started coding. I noticed that it did not recognize these imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
```

These are Java based imports. I cant tell if it just does not recognize Java imports or I didn't add Java to the programs depends

Comment: Did you try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783232/intellij-errors-java-imports-etc-doesnt-detect